# Is NodeJs http.Agent used for per instance or per host?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I would like to create connection pools per host with different settings.

```
const keepAliveAgent = new http.Agent({ 
  keepAlive: true,
  maxSockets: 2,
  keepAliveMsecs: 1000 * 60 * 60
});
```

When I use this agent with two different hosts.  Let's assume we have a code like below.

```
request({
  url: 'https://host1',
  agent: keepAliveAgent
})

request({
  url: 'https://host2',
  agent: keepAliveAgent
})
```

Are 2 sockets are dedicated for each host (4 total sockets in use) or only 2 sockets are being used for these hosts (2 total sockets in use)?

In [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_new_agent_options)

> **maxSockets**  Maximum number of sockets to allow per host. Each request will use a new socket until the maximum is reached.
>   Default: Infinity.

When I read this, I can understand that 2 + 2 sockets will be dedicated to each host resulting in a total of 4 sockets open.

But [implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/29867f35d89c9cc0ef1ea7dfdecd6361dc00a7c1/lib/https.js#L139) doesn't have any code related to this. Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you expected, a maximum of four sockets would be used, i.e. a maximum of two per host in your case. The responsible piece of code which handles this, can be found here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_agent.js#L155

The socket is (among other things) identified by the host url and will either be reused or created:

```
  var name = this.getName(options);
  if (!this.sockets[name]) {
    this.sockets[name] = [];
  }

  var freeLen = this.freeSockets[name] ? this.freeSockets[name].length : 0;
  var sockLen = freeLen + this.sockets[name].length;

  if (freeLen) {
    // we have a free socket, so use that.
    var socket = this.freeSockets[name].shift();
    // Guard against an uninitialized or user supplied Socket.
    if (socket._handle && typeof socket._handle.asyncReset === 'function') {
      // Assign the handle a new asyncId and run any init() hooks.
      socket._handle.asyncReset();
      socket[async_id_symbol] = socket._handle.getAsyncId();
    }

    // don't leak
    if (!this.freeSockets[name].length)
      delete this.freeSockets[name];

    this.reuseSocket(socket, req);
    setRequestSocket(this, req, socket);
    this.sockets[name].push(socket);
  } else if (sockLen < this.maxSockets) {
    debug('call onSocket', sockLen, freeLen);
    // If we are under maxSockets create a new one.
    this.createSocket(req, options, handleSocketCreation(this, req, true));
  } else {
    debug('wait for socket');
    // We are over limit so we'll add it to the queue.
    if (!this.requests[name]) {
      this.requests[name] = [];
    }
    this.requests[name].push(req);
  }
```

Assuming that you've already sent two requests to `host1` and the sockets have not been freed yet, the request would be queued and reassigned to one of the sockets as soon as one gets available. This code takes care of that: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_agent.js#L66